# implementing abstract methods/classes in java

Tags: java, methods, abstraction, radix, derived

Can I implement abstract methods in an abstract base class A in java?

If the answer is yes and there is an implemented abstract method in a base class A and there is a derived class B from A (B is not abstract). Does B still has to implement that base abstract method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, Yes.

```
public abstract class TopClass {
  public abstract void methodA();
  public abstract void methodB();
}

public abstract class ClassA extends TopClass {
  @Override
  public void methodA() {
    // Implementation
  }
}

public class ClassB extends ClassA {
  @Override
  public void methodB() {
    // Implementation
  }
}
```

In this example, ClassB will compile. It will use it's own implementation of methodB(), and ClassA's implementation of methodA(). You could also override methodA() in ClassB if desired.

Comment: +1, though properly speaking, I believe the answer should be "Yes and No" given that the OP actually asked two questions (you only answered the first with words, but the second with code).

Answer (score 1):

You could have two abstract classes, X and Y, where Y extends X. In that case it could make sense for Y to implement an abstract method of X, while still being abstract. Another non-abstract class Z could extend Y. However, in your example, for A to implement its own abstract methods is a contradiction, the point of making them abstract is so it doesn't provide implementations, it just specifies what the method signatures should look like.

Comment: In this case, Y is abstract because it might have other abstract methods?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement an abstract method it's not really abstract any more, so no.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes can have regular methods. If you want to implement some of the methods of class A and leave rest of the methods abstract, you can do this. However, abstract methods cannot have a body, therefore if you mark a method as abstract, then it has to be implemented by a subclass, you can't implement them in the abstract class. However, you can have an abstract class without abstract methods, then subclass only needs to extend it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can implement abstract methods in a class which is declared as abstract. If a class is declared abstract that does not mean all its method must be abstract.

For a concrete sub class, it is not mandatory to implement the abstract methods that are already implemented by one of their super class.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. Abstract methods are meant to be defined by the subclass(es). For more information, see [Abstract Methods and Classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html). However, you can define a method in the base class and have the subclass(es) override it, if required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it can't be abstract any more. Abstract means there is no implementation.

What you can do is:

```
interface I {
    void meth();
}

//and

abstract class A implements I {
    public void meth() {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

Or:

```
abstract class A {

    public abstract void meth();
}

//and

abstract class B extends A {
    public void meth() {
    }
}
```

If A already has an implementation, you can override it in B (if B is concrete), because B inherits that default implementation from A.

Comment: without implementing the base method?